# How to read env variables Elasticbeanstalk in java?

Tags: java, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application deployed in Elasticbeanstalk and I need to read and write some config variables. I tried using the usual config.properties file. While it works locally, it s not working when i deploy in on EB, because i think i dont have access in storing files.

Then what are my options?
1. store the config file in s3.
2. using the env variables UI offered by EB. In this case how i can read/write from a java application?
3. any other options?

Thnks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variables section of the beanstalk configuration then access the variables in code:

`System.getProperty("ENVIRONMENT");`

Comment: Hi can i also  set this property?